How can a container elevate it's privileges / When does the kubernetes feature `allowPrivilegeEscalation` provide protection?
I read through No New Privileges and understand, that allowPrivilegeEscalation=false can be used to prevent child processes etc. from gaining more privileges.
How could a container elevate it's privileges?
Is allowPrivilegeEscalation only good for container exploitation scenarios, or is there any other way , how a container can gain more privileges?

I realized, that I had a misunderstanding.
If you call another binary within the container which has SUID or SGID set, the child process has more permissions, and the child process is able to perform root-level operations.
The privilege escalation is the invocation of the other binary.
So no container exploit is needed, since ressources already present in the container are used.

You have actually three cases:

default: When the field is not explicitly set then the implicit
default is that that the field is true,NoNewPrivs: 0
explicit one:
When the field is explicitly set then allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
means that the container will have NoNewPrivs: 0 and
allowPrivilegeEscalation: false means that the container will have
NoNewPrivs: 1
precedance case: If the fields privileged or CAP_SYS_ADMIN are used means the container will have NoNewPrivs: 0

